# Aggregating data by groups

Tags: sql, sql-server, group

**I have this table:**

| Location | PT_ID | Visit_DT | Discharge_DT | InjuryLevel | InjuryCode | Claim_ID | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ab1 | 0001 | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 7 | I03 | clm078 | -400 |
| Ab1 | 0001 | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 1 | I03 | clm079 | 400 |
| Ab1 | 0001 | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 3 | I03 | clm068 | 500 |
| Ab1 | 0001 | 01-01-2021 | 01-03-2021 | 3 | I03 | clm008 | 75 |
| Ab2 | 0002 | 04-11-2021 | 04-12-2021 | 5 | I03 | clm111 | 1000 |
| Ab2 | 0002 | 05-01-2021 | 05-03-2021 | 5 | I03 | clm176 | 900 |
| Ab2 | 0002 | 08-08-2021 | 08-09-2021 | 6 | I03 | clm187 | 2000 |

**Whats happening:**

PT 001 visits the hospital on 01-01-2021 and there are three claims that occur on that day, all for the same visit with different injury codes recorded. I would like to pick the max injurylevel for that patient on that day (7) and indicate that they had 1 visit that was equal to InjuryLevel6to10. For patient 002, they have 3 different visits, 2 that fall under InjuryLevel1to5 and 1 in InjuryLevel6to10 (as shown below).

For both patients I would also like to add up their total cost.

**Desired Output:**

| Location | PT_ID | InjuryLevel1to5 | InjuryLevel6to10 | TotalCost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Ab1 | 0001 | 0 | 1 | 575 |
| Ab2 | 0002 | 2 | 1 | 3900 |

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: @DaleK I just added an edit that mentions I also need to pick the max injury level which I believe complicates things a little bit.

Comment: `GROUP BY` with `SUM` and `MAX`?

Comment: @DaleK I have tried  few different combinations of those and it does not seem to be working

Comment: Thats why you should show us what you tried... then we can help work out what isn't working.

Comment: @Stu if there are multiple claims during the same time span then I just want to pick the max injurylevel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Admittedly I'm not entirely sure of your criteria and your sample data needs a bit more variety to show each expected case.

However does the following work for you, or get you close?

```
select location, pt_id, 
  Sum(case when il between 1 and 5 then ct else 0 end) InjuryLevel1to5,
  Sum(case when il between 6 and 10 then ct else 0 end) InjuryLevel6to10,
  Sum(Cost) totalCost
from (
  select location, pt_id,Visit_DT, 
    Max(InjuryLevel) il, 
    Count(distinct Visit_DT) ct, 
    Sum(cost) cost
  from t
  group by location, pt_id,Visit_DT
)t
group by PT_ID, Location;
```